# Filter list on lookup column

Tags: 2010, list-view, designer-workflow

I have a list "Events" It is related to an EventsInstructors" list, using the Related List available in SP2010.

```
EVENTS
Title
EventId (number)
InstructorsNeeded (number)
InstructorsRegistered (Lookup to related EVENTINSTRUCTORS.EventId field count)

EVENTINSTRUCTORS
EventInstructorId (number)
EventId (number, = EVENTS.EventId)
InstructorId (number = INSTRUCTORS.InstructorId)
```

So you get the idea. EVENTS is a master list, and EVENTINSTRUCTORS is a detail list keeping track of which instructors signed up for which event.

That all works great. But here is the trick... I am trying to contruct a view which will show the Events which still need instructors. Looks simple enough. I can determine that by EVENTS.InstructorsNeeded - EVENTS.InstructorsRegistered. If the result is > 0, then it still needs instructors.

But again SharePoint takes what is just within my grasp, and evil clowns me. Can't use a lookup column in a view. Can't use a lookup column in a calculated column. I'm wondering what good lookup columns are at all, other than to torment SP developers.

So how do I achieve the desired result? I'm open to whatever it will take. I looked at SPD workflows, but do not see where you can do any sort of CAML querying in it, or otherwise obtaining a "COUNT()" (in the SQL sense). I'm open to ideas. SPD workflow? Custom C# thing? PowerShell Script?

I'm seeing other similar questions, but none scratch the itch. Augh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably quite a few ways to achieve this but using your current structure you could have a workflow trigger automatically when your item is entered or updated and put the value of the lookup column into a hidden text column.  That way you can use in calculated columns and also to filter views.

Comment: I was cotemplating that, but am suspecting the workflow would never fire if the EventInstructors list was edited in Datasheet View. I might have to give that a whack.